# Prove $P \lor Q, P \rightarrow R \lor S, R \rightarrow W \land Z, Z \land \lnot S \rightarrow \lnot W \vdash \lnot S \rightarrow Q$ using ND

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

The problem is to prove
$$P \lor Q, P \rightarrow R \lor S, R \rightarrow W \land Z, Z \land \lnot S \rightarrow \lnot W \vdash \lnot S \rightarrow Q$$
using natural deduction.

I'm studying natural deduction for my upcoming exam in Logic and I have come across this problem. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a path to its solution. What I have done is the following and I don't know how to proceed any further:

> 1. $P \lor Q$
> 2. $P \rightarrow R \lor S$
> 3. $R \rightarrow W \land Z$
> 4. $Z \land \lnot S \rightarrow \lnot W$
> 5. $P \qquad H$
>
>    > 6. $R \lor S \qquad E \rightarrow 2,5$
>    > 7. $R \qquad H$
>    >
>    >    > 8. $W \land Z \qquad E\rightarrow 3,7$
>    >    > 9. $W \qquad E\rightarrow 8$
>    >    > 10. $Z \qquad E\rightarrow 8$

My professor only uses the Fitch notation, so I would appreciate you using it in your answer.

EDIT: Using the suggestions in the answers provided and studying the rules some more, I have come up with this solution. Can you tell me whether it is acceptable?

$1 \quad P \lor Q
\\ 2 \quad P \rightarrow R \lor S
\\ 3 \quad R \rightarrow W \land Z
\\ 4 \quad Z \land \lnot S \rightarrow \lnot W
\\ 5 \qquad \lnot S \qquad assumption
\\ 6 \qquad \qquad P \qquad assumption
\\ 7 \qquad \qquad R \lor S \qquad implication \ elim \ 2,6
\\ 8 \qquad \qquad R \qquad disjunctive \ syll \ 7,5
\\ 9 \qquad \qquad W \land Z \qquad implication \ elim \ 3,8
\\ 10 \qquad \qquad Z \qquad conjunction \ elim \ 9
\\ 11 \qquad \qquad Z \land \lnot S \qquad conjunction \ intro \ 10,5
\\ 12 \qquad \qquad \lnot W \qquad implication \ elim \ 4,11
\\ 13 \qquad \qquad W \qquad conjunction \ elim \ 9
\\ 14 \qquad \qquad false \qquad negation \ elim \ 13,12
\\ 15 \qquad \lnot P \qquad negation \ intro \ 14
\\ 16 \qquad Q \qquad disjunctive \ syll \ 1,15
\\ 17 \quad \lnot S \rightarrow Q \qquad implication \ intro \ 5,16$

Comment: Please make sure the question is stated clearly in the body of your post - the title is not part of the post and may not be read by everyone.

Comment: It seems that we cannot prove it ... If $v(S)=$ **t** the conclusion is *false*. But then $P \to R \lor S$ is *true* and also $Z \land \lnot S \to \lnot W$ is *true*. Finally, we may satisfy both $P \lor Q$ and $R \to W \land Z$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: indeed

Comment: You have to start from $P \lor Q$ and use $\lor$-elim. The "branch with $Q$ will produce immediately $\lnot S \to Q$, while the "branch" with $P$ needs the other premises.

Answer (score 1):

We have to start from $P \lor Q$ and use $∨$elim [see [here](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) for the ND rules used].

The branch starting with $Q$ will be :

$1_Q)$ $Q$ --- assumed for $\lor$-elim

> > A) $\lnot S \to Q$ --- from 1) by $\to$-intro.

For the "branch" starting with $P$ we have :

$1_P)$ $P$ --- assumed for $\lor$-elim

2) $R \lor S$ --- from 1) and 2nd premise by $\to$-elim

3) $S$ --- assumed [a] from 2) for $\lor$-elim

4) $\lnot S$ --- assumed [b]

5) $\bot$ --- contradiction : from 3) and 4) by $\lnot$-elim

6) $Q$ --- from 5) by $\bot$-elim

> 7) $\lnot S \to Q$ --- from 4) and 6) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b].

Now for :

8) $R$ --- assumed [c] for $\lor$-elim

9) $W \land Z$ --- from 8) and 3rd premises by $\to$-elim

10) $W$ --- from 9) by $\land$-elim

11) $Z$ --- from 9) by $\land$-elim

12) $\lnot S$ --- assumed [d]

13) $Z \land \lnot S$ --- from 11) and 12) by $\land$-intro

14) $\lnot W$ --- from 13) and 4th premise by $\to$-elim

15) $\bot$ --- contradiction : from 10) and 14) by $\lnot$-elim

16) $Q$ --- from 15) by $\bot$-elim

17) $\lnot S \to Q$ --- from 12 and 16) by $\to$-intro, discharging [d]

> > B) $\lnot S \to Q$ --- from 2), 3)-7) and 8)-9) by $\lor$-elim, discharging [a] and [c].

Now from A), B) and the 1st premise: $P \lor Q$, we conclude by $\lor$-elim with:

> $\lnot S \to Q$,

discharging assumptions $1_Q)$ and $1_P)$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to reach the contradiction we want using 3) and 4).

Comment: @diliad - 3) $S$ and 4) $\lnot S$ **is** the contradiction; if you want, tou can use $\land$-intro to get: $S \land \lnot S$. But the rule $\lnot$-elim does not need it.

Comment: What I cannot understand is what leads us to $\lnot S$, when we make the assumption that S is true after inferring that $R \lor S$.

Comment: @diliad - I've assumed it. Then I've discharged it in 7).

Answer (score 0):

The question asks us to prove $\lnot S \to Q$ from the following hypothesis:

1. $P \lor Q$
2. $P \to R \lor S$
3. $R \to W \land Z$
4. $Z \land \lnot S \to \lnot W$

Let's think about how this could go wrong. It is claimed that if $S$ is false and all four hypotheses hold, then $Q$ is true. So, for a contradiction, assume $S$ is false and $Q$ is false.

If $Q$ is false, then $P$ is true by item 1. Then $R \lor S$ is true by item $2$. We have assumed $S$ is false, so $R$ must be true.

Now, by item 3, $W$ and $Z$ must be true. Finally, by item 4, because $Z$ is true and $S$ is false, $W$ must be false. This is a contradiction, which is what we wanted.

That argument can be turned into a proof by natural deduction. However, instead of assuming $P$ at line 5 of your deduction above, you want to assume $\lnot S$. This is because you are trying to prove an implication whose hypothesis is $\lnot S$, and so you want to put yourself in a position to use implication introduction to do that. Assuming $P$ will not help as directly.

Then, at the next step, you can assume $\lnot Q$. Eventually, you will be able to derive a contradiction, which will let you deduce $Q$.

So the outline looks like this:

1. Hypothesis 1
2. Hypothesis 2
3. Hypothesis 3
4. Hypothesis 4
5. $\lnot S$ (assumption)

   5.1. $\lnot Q$ (assumption)

   5.2. ...

   5.3. ...

   5.4. contradiction

   5.5. $Q$ (contradiction rule, discharge 5.1)
6. $\lnot S \to Q$ (implication introduction, discharge 5)

---

To handle the implication $P\lor Q, \not Q \vdash P$, you can use something like this.

1. $P \lor Q$  - assumption
2. $Q$  - assumption
3. $\lnot Q$ - assume for $\lor$ elimination from 1

   3.1 Contradiction with 2
   3.2 Conclude $P$, discharge 3
4. $P$ - assume for $\lor$ elimination from 1

   4.1 Conclude $Q$ from 2, discharge 4
5. $Q$ - $\lor$ elimination from 1, 3, 4

Comment: If I understand this right, after the assumption that Q is false, we can directly infer that, by item 1, P must be true? Although it's very obvious that this holds, I can't think of how to correctly write it down using the basic Natural Deduction rules.

Comment: You can't do it in just one step. You need to use the disjunction elimination rule. Basically, you just have to include a deduction of $(P \lor Q),\lnot Q \vdash P$ inside your larger deduction.

Comment: I don't understand can you please further explain

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array} {l|l}
\lnot S & \text{New Assumption} \\
\quad P & \text{New Assumption}  \\
\quad \quad \vdots \\
\quad \quad \bot \\
\quad \lnot P & \lnot \text{Intro} \\
\quad P \lor Q & \text{Given} \\
\quad \vdots \\
\quad Q & \lor\text{Elim} \\
\lnot S \implies Q & \implies \text{Intro} \\
\end{array}$$

Can you fill in the $\vdots$ ?

Comment: I cannot find a way to create the contradiction needed after assuming that P is true. Maybe I'm missing something or it's my foggy head to blame, or even both.

Comment: Hint: in the first $\vdots$, you can infer $S \implies W \land Z$ (since $\lnot S$ is under assumption, you can infer $S \implies \text{ anything}$).  You should be able to derive a contradiction among the $W$.

Answer (score -1):

After an edit the OP asks the following:

> Using the suggestions in the answers provided and studying the rules some more, I have come up with this solution. Can you tell me whether it is acceptable?

One way to tell if a proof is likely acceptable is to put it in a proof checker. Since the OP is using a similar Fitch-style natural deduction system as presented by *forallx*, the proof checker associated with that text could be used to see if the proof is acceptable.  Here is the result:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/